# my express endpoint route with mysql logs an error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1

Tags: javascript, mysql, express

I'm building a web app for a bootcamp. I'm using express and mysql. I'm routing a get request to an endpoint. The route should query my mysql database table to select all. I'm expecting to send the result to the chrome page. Instead I get this error:

```
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:8211
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1054:14)
    --------------------
    at Protocol._enqueue (/Users/cnebs/Documents/HRATX/hratx42-fullstack-review/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:144:48)
    at Protocol.handshake (/Users/cnebs/Documents/HRATX/hratx42-fullstack-review/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:51:23)
    at Connection.connect (/Users/cnebs/Documents/HRATX/hratx42-fullstack-review/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:119:18)
    at Connection._implyConnect (/Users/cnebs/Documents/HRATX/hratx42-fullstack-review/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:457:10)
    at Connection.query (/Users/cnebs/Documents/HRATX/hratx42-fullstack-review/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:199:8)
    at Object.getAllUsers (/Users/cnebs/Documents/HRATX/hratx42-fullstack-review/database/index.js:17:14)
    at /Users/cnebs/Documents/HRATX/hratx42-fullstack-review/server/index.js:22:6
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/cnebs/Documents/HRATX/hratx42-fullstack-review/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at next (/Users/cnebs/Documents/HRATX/hratx42-fullstack-review/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:137:13)
    at Route.dispatch (/Users/cnebs/Documents/HRATX/hratx42-fullstack-review/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:112:3) {
  errno: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  syscall: 'connect',
  address: '127.0.0.1',
  port: 8211,
  fatal: true
}
```

I'm able to query the database in terminal. I'm able to send text to the page on chrome through express. I've built a database and table. I haven't used the api for my project to populate the table yet. My console is logging the error through a function in my database index which I've imported to express to be used in the get route.

Here is the database index:

```
const mysql = require('mysql');
const connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host: "127.0.0.1",
  user: "root",
  password: "password",
  database: "github",
  port: 8211
});

const test = () => {
  connection.query("DESCRIBE git_repos", (err, res) => {
    console.log('selection: ', res)
  })
}

const getAllUsers = cb => {
  connection.query(`select * from todos`, (err, res) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log("error in getAllUsers: ", err);
      cb(err);
    } else {
      cb(null, res);
    }
  });
}

module.exports = { test, getAllUsers }
```

Here is the server index:

```
const express = require('express');
const db = require('../database')
let app = express();


app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/../client/dist'));

app.get('/repos', function (req, res) {
  // TODO - your code here!
  // This route should send back the top 25 repos

  db.getAllUsers((err, result) => {
    if (err) {
      console.error(err)
      res.status(404).end();
    } else {
      console.log('Getting')
      res.send(result)
    }
  })
});

let port = 1128;

app.listen(port, function() {
  console.log(`listening on port ${port}`);
});
```

I expect to see any result at all from my query delivered to the page from the res.send.

Instead, I see that the localhost page can't be found and the err response above in my server terminal.

Answer (score 0):

You aren't able to directly choose the port for your database server in the createConnection(). Remove the port property and it will function.